# How to monitor a group of twitter accounts

Tags: search, twitter

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a list of twitter users (2-3000) whose tweets I need to monitor for keywords.

I thought of two solutions to implement that but don't think any is optimal.

1- Create a private list on twitter, add all the accounts i want to monitor and use the list api to get all the tweets

2- use the search or stream api to monitor all of twitter for my keywords and then cross check on my side with the list of users i have.

Are these the only ways to do it? any idea on how to be more efficient?

One thing to keep in mind, I need to keep the list of accounts I'm monitoring private. Every account holder can know he is followed but can't know who else is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is how I would do it:

1) create an account on twitter that will follow all these people

2) I presume you have this list of people stored somehow, parse/grep/format that data so you have a list of all their user_ids

3) create an twitter application for you to use

4) download you favorite languages most popular twitter library

5) authenticate your user with your application

<s>6) create a simple little program that reads your list from 2 and works it's way through following those users. Put a sleep between these calls as you will be subject to rate limiting.</s>

6) create a simple little program that reads your list from (2) and works it's way through adding each user to a private list, creating a new private list each time you hit the 500 cap. These calls are subject to rate limiting, so stagger or batch the calls over the required time window

7) now you simply query your timeline via the API and you are away.

Key thing is 2, if you have that list in some digital format(text file,database,someone else's followers) or somehow is able to calculated (read:avoid manual search and follow) , this should be a breeze.

I use java, you could do everything in my steps + your filtering requirements with scribe (auth library) and gson (Json parser) in a couple methods. In terms of cleanliness and efficiency, I think this fits the brief.

Comment: This is what I had in mind, but instead of following the people I am going to create a private list an add them to that list.

Comment: Lists don't give you anything extra + they are capped to 500 members.

Comment: There's one thing i forgot to mention, I need to have the list of accounts I'm following stay private. I can't have someone have access to the list of people I am following. I modified the question to reflect that.

Comment: @chaft Changed step 6 to accommodate additional requirement.

Comment: After some experimenting i found out some interesting things, for some reason you cannot follow your own private lists, so there's no way to add people to a private list and follow that list. 2 every account is limited to creating 20 lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stream API to follow multiple accounts, too, with the `follow` parameter, and then search by keyword on your end.  That would be a lot more efficient.

You can also follow people with [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline), although it's only one user at a time.  You can get 200 posts back in the past though.

I would do the streaming API, but also write some code to use `user_timeline`, in case your streaming receiving thing ever goes down you'll be able to quickly get anything you missed.